# Xamarin Forms Maps - Set Bearing (Maps Api)

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a map centric app and having a small issue .

I am displaying my map and getting current location . I can see the blue dot on the map and the directional arrow appears sometimes .

However i can't find any way to set the bearing . (or set the arrow to the direction the phone is pointing at)

Such as in google maps app , when you move the phone around - you can see the user position showing a directional fog towards where the phone is pointing .

I am using the compass plugin and getting the compass reading between 0-360 , however i'm not sure how to add that to my map + user location to make the arrow point in that direction.

Any ideas how to proceed ?

Comment: Which plugin are you using for your Xamarin Forms Map? [This one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing named Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps which can set bearing like Google Maps API.

[amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps: Map library for Xamarin.Forms using Google maps API](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps)

```
// No animation
await map.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(
    new CameraPosition(
        new Position(35.7104, 139.8093), // center
        17d, // zoom
        45d, // bearing(rotation)
        60d))); // tilt

// With animation
await map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(
    new CameraPosition(
        new Position(35.7104, 139.8093), // center
        17d, // zoom
        45d, // bearing(rotation)
        60d)), // tilt
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```